# Javascript upload image using ajax without user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cloudsight

I am trying to send an image to an image recognition API called Cloudsight. I have gotten it working using a URL, and am now trying to get it to send a local image. The thing is, it can't require any user interaction, as it all has to happen automatically. The answers I've seen use FormData, but as it can't require user interaction I don't think I can use it. (unless there's a way to use it to upload something automatically.) The code currently is:

```js
var token; //Variable for use later

//First AJAX request.
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { // Authorizes the request.
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
      "CloudSight [key]");
  },
  data: { // The data to send.
    "image_request[image]": //the image needs to go here,
    "image_request[locale]": "en-US"
  },
  success: function(msg) { // What should happen if succesful.
    console.log("It worked! :D Good POST request.");
    console.log(msg);

    token = msg.token; // Assigns the token the POST request returns to the token variable.

    get(); // Calls the function containing the GET request.
  },
  error: function(msg) { // What should happen if not succesful.
    console.log("Sorry...");
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

All I need is something to send the local file; how do I upload the image without user interaction?

Comment: Fortunately, no browser will let you write code that takes data from a users computer and upload it somewhere without their knowledge

Comment: Makes sense, thinking about it... there's no workaround or anything then? I'm doing it on a Pi; is there a way to get the Pi to click and choose the file automatically?

Comment: Are you trying to automatically send a file from your own server to CloudSight?

Comment: You can't upload without user interaction due to security reason.

Comment: Of course, a correctly written addon (firefox and chrome at least) may give such ability, that does not violate the **security** concerns, as an addon (at least a firefox one) would have to be "signed" by mozilla, so it stands to reason that a user installing such an addon would be perfectly aware of it's function

Comment: Okay; I think I may just have to recode it in Python (which makes sense as it's going to be on a Pi), but I'll look into addons as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can do

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');
in a netscape-compatible browser (Firefox, Mozilla, Netscape), and it will ask the user* whether or not to allow filesystem access, but this is not portable.

*once per browser processQ